# Unable to cast TEXT to XML in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005

Basically I have a column named `XML` that is of type `TEXT`; this cannot be changed for other reason, but I was wondering how I could cast it to XML.

It gives me an error

> XML parsing: line 1, character 39, unable to switch the encoding

when trying to do this. Is there anyways around it to still get it formatted to XML? I'm really stuck at this point.

Data within column:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Record>
     <UserGuid>c624a356-9f18-403c-b404-790e79034c7d</UserGuid>
</Record>
```

Here is the cast SQL code:

```
SELECT CAST(XML AS XML).value('(/Record/UserGuid)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(max)')
FROM tbl_Module_RequestForms_Items
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Your problem is: you have XML with an `encoding="utf-16"`, but your column is a non-Unicode column......

Assuming that you cannot change it to `NTEXT` either, you have to do **two nested `CAST`** to achieve what you're looking for:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(CAST(XML AS NTEXT) AS XML).value('(/Record/UserGuid)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(max)')
FROM 
    tbl_Module_RequestForms_Items
```

First, you need to cast to `NTEXT` (or `NVARCHAR(MAX)`), and then you have to cast that result to `XML`, before you can use it.

**Tip:** remove those "other reasons" and convert this to `XML` datatype if you really need to use it as XML .....

Comment: Getting ´illegal xml character´ error if I try this method. SQL Server 2008 R2. Any ideas?

Comment: @Azimuth: sounds like a new question - and be sure to post the sample XML !

Comment: @Azimuth: make that a question on SO!  I'm sure some of the XML gurus will see it and respond to it ....

Comment: @marc_s, I did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20116205/xml-parsing-illegal-character-in-the-end-of-the-string

Comment: Wish I could upvote this answer twice thank you so much

Answer (score 41):

You should replace `encoding="utf-16"` to `encoding="utf-8"` or `''(blank)` and then perform your operation.

a. Converting `encoding="utf-16"` to `encoding="utf-8"`

```
SELECT 
  CAST(
    REPLACE(CAST([xml] AS VARCHAR(MAX)), 'encoding="utf-16"', 'encoding="utf-8"')
  AS XML).value('(/Record//UserGuid/node())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(max)') as UserGuid
from tbl_Module_RequestForms_Items
```

b. Replacing `encoding="utf-16"` to `''(blank)`

```
SELECT 
  CAST(
    REPLACE(CAST([xml] AS VARCHAR(MAX)), 'encoding="utf-16"', '')
  AS XML).value('(/Record//UserGuid/node())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(max)') as UserGuid
from tbl_Module_RequestForms_Items
```

Comment: I wish i could mark both right, you and Marc_s both had methods that worked great. I upvoted yours though. Thanks again!

Comment: Hello @thesandman, thank you for supporting, I've up voted you too. I tried by best to answer you properly in several ways. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Casting back and forth didn’t work for me, but removing the explicit `encoding="UTF-8"` as suggested here did the trick.

Answer (score 4):

Casting XML variable as NTEXT solves the problem 
`CAST(CAST (XML AS NTEXT) AS XML)`.

Comment: This is an underrated answer.

Answer (score 3):

Replacing encoding="utf-8" to encoding="utf-16" worked for me :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the encoding before casting to XML.

```
CAST (REPLACE(MyTextToCastToXML, 'utf-8', 'utf-16') AS XML)
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `CONVERT` instead of `CAST`?

```
SELECT CONVERT(XML, @xml).value('(/Record/UserGuid)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(max)')
from tbl_Module_RequestForms_Items
```

Also, check out the "xml styles" section of this page; it contains some options you have when converting xml:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: Doesn't work either .... none of the four styles available works, because the input is basically Unicode, but the datatype it's stored in is non-Unicode