# XML parsing, illegal character in the end of the string

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm getting very strange error when I trying to convert a string to XML in MS SQL Server:

> Msg 9420, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   XML parsing: line 1, character 8071, illegal xml character

If I check the string in some text editor, I can see that its length is 8070. Why is it complaining about character 8071 if it does not exist?

This is how I'm converting string to XML:

```
CAST(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ResponseData,'ä','a'),'ö','o'),'å','a'), 
PATINDEX('%<?xml%',ResponseData), PATINDEX('%sonType>', ResponseData)+6),
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>', 
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>')as XML) as ResponseData
```

Are any of replaces causing the problem?

UPD: The problem also is that in `ResponseData` column the XML string is stored together with some other data. Example:

```
Error from service: <Some error description>. Sent request: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><Contents of the XML>
```

So I need to get that XML string from the column and then convert it to XML.

Comment: Why are you replacing the header with `encoding="utf-16"` with `encoding="utf-8"` ?? That might cause the issue - can you try *without* doing this replacement step? Also: what is the datatype of the `ResponseData` column in your table??

Comment: @marc_s without that replacement I get `unable to switch the encoding` error. The column `ResponseData` is of type `varchar(max)`.

Comment: You'll need to use `CONVERT` and do **two steps** in converting your column:  `CAST(CAST(ResponseData as NVARCHAR(max)) AS XML)` - first you need to convert `ResponseData` to **NVARCHAR** since you're defining it to be `utf-16` (= Unicode) encoding, and secondly, you need to use `CAST` again to convert that result to `XML`. This way, you **don't need** to remove that header from your content

Comment: @marc_s now I'm getting this error: `text/xmldecl not at the beginning of input`. Also, see my update of the question

Comment: @marc_s if I try to convert first to `nvarchar` and then to `XML`, I still get that error, `illegal xml character` and it's pointing at the character `string length + 1`

Comment: What a mess that is! Can't you separate the actual XML into a separate column of type `XML` ?? That would make things **just SOOOO much easier!**

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41627/discussion-between-azimuth-and-marc-s)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change original encoding from `UTF-16` to `ISO-8859-1`, or a more precise encoding for your characters:

```
DECLARE @data varchar(max) = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><...>' 
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(@data, 
            '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>',
            '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>') AS XML) ResponseData
```