# Extract value from a sql column that contains XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I'm trying to get the value from a column in a SQL Server table that contains XML but the type of the column is not `XML` it is `TEXT`.

I tried this:

```
SELECT 
    [Id],
    [Request]
FROM 
    [Tracker] 
WHERE 
    [Request].value('/Credit[1]/Loan[1]/LoanApp[1]/Applicant[1]/Personal[1]/Individals[1]/Individual[1]/GivenName[1]/FirstName[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') = 'Tom'
```

but I get this error :

> Cannot find either column "Request" or the user-defined function or aggregate "Request.value", or the name is ambiguous.

I tried to cast the column like this:

```
select  
    CAST(CAST(Request AS NTEXT) AS XML).value('(/Credit[1]/Loan[1]/LoanApp[1]/Applicant[1]/Personal[1]/Individuals[1]/Individual[1]/GivenName[1]/FirstName[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') 
from Tracker
```

but with this I get this error:

> XML parsing: line 1, character 15, A string literal was expected

I tried the solution in this link:
[Unable to cast TEXT to XML in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334902/unable-to-cast-text-to-xml-in-sql-server)

```
  XML parsing: line 1, character 15, A string literal was expected
```

This is what I have tried:

```
 SELECT 
  CAST(
  REPLACE(CAST(Request AS VARCHAR(MAX)), 'encoding="utf-16"',   'encoding="utf-8"')
AS     XML).value('(Credit/Loan/App/Applicant/Personal/Individuals/Individual/GivenName/FirstName/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(max)') as UserGuid
 FROM Tracker
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to cast TEXT to XML in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334902/unable-to-cast-text-to-xml-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your casting is correct

```
select  CAST(CAST(Request AS NTEXT)AS  
   XML).value('(/Credit[1]/Loan[1]/LoanApp[1]/Applicant[1]/Personal[1]/Individuals[1]/Individual[1]/GivenName[1]/FirstName[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') 

from Tracker]
```

But one of the possible reasons you are getting the error is you haven't specified the attributes in a single or double quote.

As an example you have `<credit id=12>` in your `Request` text field and you need to change it to `<credit id='12'>` or `<credit id="12">` before casting it to XML.

Comment: but I cannot change XML it is 100000 record with XML in the table that I shouldn't change them, my code should be in a way that work with it.

Answer (score 0):

Cast your object to `String` and then use `XmlTextReader` and `ReadXml`.